# Flutter. Dart. Flutter - replacing a item in a list

Tags: list, flutter, dart, replace

```
List<int> myList = [1,2,3];
int i = 2;
myList[i] = 4; // myList = [1,2,4]
```

but what if i don't know whether myList contains data at specific index? Then it gives me range error.

```
i = 4;
myList[i] = 4 // range error
if(myList[i] != null) myList[i] = 4 //range error
myList.insert(i, 4) // i want to replace, not shift values.
```

Is the only way to replace the list value at specific index is by checking the whole list length first?

Comment: You first line of question is wrong. `List<myList> = [1,2,3];` in that where is variable name. what is type of list? I think its int as per your given data. Please provide valid infomation.

Comment: Even though I posted my answer (for int). you can check it out.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the example that you can check the index before and If that condition is true then only it will update the value.

```
void main() {
  List<int> myList1 = [1,2,3];
  int i = 2;
  if(myList1.length> i) myList1[i] = 4; // myList = [1,2,4]
  myList1.forEach(print);
  
  
  int j = 5;
  if(myList1.length> j) myList1[j] = 4; // myList = [1,2,4]
  myList1.forEach(print); // It will print as it is last one.
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

From what I understood, you want to know if there is any other way to check whether or not the index exists for your list.
If So then:

```dart
List<int> myList = [1,2,3];
int i = 2;
if(myList.asMap().containsKey(i)) myList[i] = 4
```

Let me know if I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Yes for sure, but, are there more productive way to do it, just out of box? If not this is an option.

Comment: `myList = myList.map((e) => e == 2 ? 4 : e).toList();`

Answer (score 1):

try like this:

```
if(i<=myList.length){
 myList[i]=4;
 }
```